# AI in different-shaped planets - Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I am currently working in a Unity 3D project (in version 5.0.1 to be precise) in which the character can walk in different-shaped planets without falling. So it is always attracted by the planets gravity (similar mechanic to the Super Mario Galaxy games).

Now, the problem is when I try to code the AI for the enemies. This AI should be pretty much simple, but because of this thing that I have with the planets shapes, I haven't been able to come up with a solution. The enemy should check where the player is and move ahead to its position. It's a really dumb enemy. But the thing is, that the enemy must be able to track the player and get to its position no matter what planet he is in. So, if the planet is circular, I cannot make the enemy look at the player and then move forward, as I would do in a plane planet.

I have already tried using a NavMesh, but Unity doesn't want to collaborate and ends up making a NavMesh of 1/3 of the planet. I don't understand why. I have tried changing every single parameter of the NavMesh baking but I haven't succeeded.

Another problem that I would like to do is: ¿How would you make a player be able to walk on the surface of any planet, no matter what its shape, in a smooth way while using a Mesh Collider? I am currently achieving this by getting the planet's normal with a raycast, rotating the player so that the Y axis is perpendicular to the normal and applying a force in -Y to simulate gravity. But this brings lots of problems when I implement the Mesh Collider. It results in a jittery effect. But, when I use a primitive collider from Unity, it works fine...

Anyway. What I need the most now is the answer to the AI question. The other one is kinda like a plus.

P.S: It doesn't matter if the solution is in Javascript. I can then translate it to C# :)

Comment: When you say circular planet, you mean spherical?, is the problem that maybe the enemy is at the other side of the sphere and making the enemy look at the player makes it face the floor?

Comment: Yes. I mean spherical. Sorry for that. It's exactly what you are saying. If I made the enemy look at the player it would face the floor and therefore be useless. Bear in mind that I gave this spherical planet as an example. But it could also be a capsule or a torus knot or whatever 3D figure you can think about. So it's really tricky...

Comment: Yeah... sounds very difficult and I have no idea on how to solve it. The only thing that comes to my mind would be to get a plane equivalent of the shape in question, it would be like when you go to Google Maps and see a plane map of the Earth, and having the plane then use a path planning algorithm to find the player. This is tricky for weird shapes, I have no idea if it's even possible for all forms. I guess other solutions are better, but it's the best I can come up with. Good luck!

Comment: That's actually a good solution. Or, at least, it's the best I have heard! I'll try that and tell you what I can accomplish. Thank you for everything!!

Comment: Well, I haven't been able to come up with a solution. So what I did was make the enemy choose a random direction upon its creation and then move straight forward until he finds that the player is inside a determined radius from him. This radius is set so that the curvature of the planet doesn't affect the enemies movement when rotating it so that he faces the player. Then, it starts following the player. This is the best I could think of, and it has got me out of the trouble for a while. It's not the best solution, but it works for now. If I can think of something better, I'll post again.